# How do I get the index of a row in pandas if the row contains ALL items in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have some excel files that are not always structured the same; so I'm reading the pandas dataframe with the headers=None parameter.

I'm then doing some checks to get the header row index position. 
I have a list of mandatory columns I need to check against before passing the row index.

`mandatory_cols = ['items','name','email']`

My dataframe:

```
 0     NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
 1     NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
 2     NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
 3     items    email    name     store
 4     2        test     Mike     2
```

I need to return `3` since row 3 contains all of the items contained in my list.  If any are missing return None.

I've looked at `df.isin(mandatory_cols)` but it seems to only return a dataframe of bools, I can't seem to figure out how to get only the index.

Some things to note, the column positions may be out of order in the files so I need to be able to look through all columns dynamically with this check.  Also the row can contain more than just the mandatory_cols, as long as it has all the mandatory columns I would want the index position.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you should using `issubset`, rather than `isin`

```
df[[set(mandatory_cols).issubset(x) for x in df.values.tolist()]].index
Out[1098]: Int64Index([3], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Can also use `apply` if you don't want to make a list of all df values (may be very big) : `df.apply(lambda k: set(mandatory_cols).issubset(k), 1)`

Comment: @RafaelC if you test the speed , apply is slow than for loop

Comment: But will it use as much memory?

Comment: @RafaelC if you can you can test it :-) and feel free to edit the timing back :-)

Comment: Thanks it will be interesting to see the difference!